# Is there a way to count all elements of an index in ElasticSearch or Tire?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

It would be nice to have a count of elements without having to do a search like

```
Obj.search("id:*").count
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you should use the `match_all` query: `MyModel.search( { query { all } }).results.total`. (In Lucene, avoid wildcard queries at all costs.)

Presently, Tire does not expose the "count" API. That will change.

Comment: Isn't there the count query available in tire?

Comment: If I use `MyModel.search(query: { match_all: {} }).results.total` I get a max count of 10000, the default value for the setting "index.max_result_window".

Answer (score 10):

In ElasticSearch you can count all elements using the count API

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/index/_count
```

See the [Count API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/count.html) docs on their site.

Answer (score 9):

Just got a hint from Karmi. The count API is available now.

You can do the following:

```
s = Tire.search 'articles-test', :search_type => 'count' do
  query { term :tags, 'ruby' }
end
```

Only then `s.results.total` is defined.

See here: https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/count_test.rb

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using gem 'elasticsearch-model', here is a nice one liner:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client.count(index: 'your_index_name_here')['count']
```

Answer (score 2):

From console:

```
Model.search("*:*").results.total
```

maybe help someone ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the `elasticsearch-model` gem as well:

```
Article.search("cats", search_type: 'count').results.total
# => 2026
```

And you won't cause a fetch...

```
Article.search("cats", search_type: 'count').map {|r| r.title}
# => []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get number of documents inside index, you could also just check [index stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html), like this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_stats
```

In result you will get number of docs / deleted docs (docs not yet merged out).

Answer (score 0):

When I use `MyModel.search(query: { match_all: {} }).results.total`, the maximum count I receive is 10000, which is the default value for the "index.max_result_window" setting. Therefore, I don't believe this is the correct answer.

Instead, my solution is to utilize the count API, which in Ruby would look like this:

```rb
Elasticsearch::Model.client.count(index: MyModel.index_name)['count']
```